# Apache throws 502 bad gateway after some time

Tags: apache, plesk, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04` with `Plesk`. After some time that everything has been okay, all the webpages from Plesk throw 502 bad gateway errors for no obvious reason. As soon as I type the command `service apache2 restart`, everything's alright again.

Oddly, it states

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx
```

despite using Apache instead of nginx.

Comment: nginx is front-end web server which handle requests before Apache, "502 Bad Gateway" means that apache was down by some reason(it's an actual root cause which should be investigated, it maybe OOM(out-of-memory) killer). You may check system and apache's logs, and monitor apache activity.